# Mezzanine (Django) menu tree generation from lower branch level

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I have the following menu structure:

> Personal
>
> > PersonalOption1
> >
> > > Sub-Option1
> > >
> > > Sub-Option2
> >
> > PersonalOption2
>
> Enterprise
>
> > EnterpriseOption1
> >
> > EnterpriseOption2

From the Page on Sub-Option1, I'm trying to generate a page_menu to only show:

- PersonalOption1
- PersonalOption2

But based on the branch_level value, I'm getting:

- PersonalOption1
- PersonalOption2
- Enterprise
- EnterpriseOption1
- EnterpriseOption2

This is the tree I'm getting using branch_level to identify each node:

> Personal (branch_level: 0)
>
> > PersonalOption1 (branch_level: 1)
> >
> > > Sub-Option1 (branch_level: 2)
> > >
> > > Sub-Option2 (branch_level: 2)
> >
> > PersonalOption2 (branch_level: 1)
> >
> > Enterprise (branch_level: 1)
> >
> > EnterpriseOption1 (branch_level: 1)
> >
> > EnterpriseOption2 (branch_level: 1)

**Enterprise** should have branch_level 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello if you are far ahead in your development i am sorry for you. If not, run away as far as you can from mezzanine. The documentation for this CMS is scarce.

Lucky for you you can solve this by using "page.branch_level" instead of just "branch_level". The former, will give you the depth of the current branch, and the latter will give you the depth of the page related to the page tree. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Silly rabbit... That did it!